# How can I access the text contained in QLabel using a loop?

Tags: qt, qlabel

For example, there are 4 Qlabels named `label_1`, `label_2`, `label_3` and `label_4`. Each has a different value and I want to access the value contained in each of them one by one using any loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put those labels in a container like a `QVector<QLabel*>` instead of giving each of them a name, then access via a loop isn't a problem at all - just look them up in the vector by index.

If for some reason you have to declare those four labels independently, there's no problem with having a list of them on top of that as another class member.

In your class:

```
 QVector<QLabel*> labels;
```

In your constructor:

```
 // build the four labels
 labels.append(label_1);
 labels.append(label_2);
 ...
```

Iterate over them:

```
 foreach (QLabel *l, labels) {
   // whatever with l
 }
 for (unsigned i = 0; i < labels.size(); i++) {
   // whatever with labels[i]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! but actually the list might be quite long, **spanning over 100s to 500** qlabels. Wouldn't the listing of all the labels at the top be a problem. 
Also, would like to access them in a different class, can you suggest something with that?

Comment: "listing of all the labels at the top be a problem" - certainly. Use a table view or something. That's a UX thing, unrelated to the above. There's nothing special about widgets or containers regarding access from other instances, plain C++ rules apply.